# Formatting small text next to large text using CSS

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I have been trying to place a smaller biography style text next to this large title, but I cannot seem to find a solution. I have tried several things like float: left and float: right and also display: flex. I provided my code and a screenshot of the current container where the text is located.

-my css

```
.toptext{
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 250px;
    height: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.biotext{
    float:right;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

-my html

```
 <div class="container-fluid bg-2">
        <h1 class="biotext">This site serves as a creative outlet and condensed center for those things that interest
            my unique sneaker collection, and my adoration for gaming that I spread through several social mediums.
        </h1>
        <h1 class="toptext">Hi, I'M</h1>
        <h1 class="toptext">ANDREW.</h1>
    </div>
```

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGdWL.png)

Comment: Please place a code snippet in your post to better help readers to answer your question.

Comment: place your code within quotes like
 ```                    
code
 ```

Answer (score 1):

the property of h1 is 'display:bolock" in default.
So you need to change this.

-css

```
.toptext{
   
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 250px;
    height: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.biotext{
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the size of top-text